# How can you enumerate all prime factors of a number in a set

Tags: notation

If you want to enumerate all elements of the following set:

> All $x$ that are prime factors of the number 3528.

If you just write 
$$
A = \{2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 7\}
$$
it is not correct because each element should be unique.

How can you solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance

How shall I put it? 
It should be possible to describe any set, either in an enumerative or in an descriptive way. 
I want to have a very special set. My set is:
"All numbers that are the result of my prime factor framentation".

Comment: What are you asking?  Are you just looking for the answer $\{2,3,7\}$?

Comment: I do not only want to enumerate the numbers per se in my set, but also the quantity of each prime factor.

Comment: that's not in your question.  What's wrong with writing  the usual prime factorization, $3528=2^33^27^2$?  You can write it as $\{(2,3),(3,2),(7,2)\}$ if you want it to look more like a set.

Comment: Thank you lulu, this looks very good to me. If you write it as an answer I will select it.

Answer (score 0):

Given any number N and then factorise it. We will get N=a^2*b^2*c^2.. where a, b and c are the prime factors of the number N.After factorising the number then write the set as { a,b,c,.. } which consist of all prime factors of N. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, lulu, for giving me this hint with the tuples.

My set is very special. The set is not only the prime factors (per se) of the number $3528$, but the result, when I perform a prime factor framentation of the number $3528$, which are the numbers $2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 7$.

When I use tuples within the set, it is possible to write the set:
$$
A = \{ (2,2,2), (3,3), (7,7) \}
$$